# filter array by key value argument

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as:

```
  $data = array(
      array('title'=>'test','rendor'=>0),
      array('title'=>'test2','rendor'=>1)
  );
```

What I am looking for is using one of the array functions to return the title key value when rendor is `1`;

Currently im doing:

```
    $tmp = array();
    $deadTmp = array();
    foreach($tmpCols as $col){          
        if((int)$col['rendor'] !== 0){
            $tmp[] = $col;
        } else {
            $deadTmp[] = $col['title'];
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to learn the array functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `array_reduce` will do:

```
$titles = array_reduce($data, function (array $titles, array $datum) {
    if ($datum['rendor'] == 1) {
        $titles[] = $datum['title'];
    }
    return $titles;
}, []);
```

Alternatively:

```
$titles = array_map(
    function ($datum) { return $datum['title']; }, 
    array_filter($data, function ($datum) { return $datum['render'] == 1; }
);
```